# Pyramid of asterisks in php

Tags: php

I am having problem creating a pyramid of asterisk.
Please see my code.

```
  <?php

    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
                    echo "*";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }

    ?>
```

Result:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

My question is how I am going to make that like.

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Comment: You will need to derive a formula that prints spaces in addition to the one you are using to print asterisks. Also, the inner loop can be replaced with a call to [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a pyramid from using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12800236/1226894)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<pre><?php

$n = $i = 5;

while ($i--)
    echo str_repeat(' ', $i).str_repeat('* ', $n - $i)."\n";

?></pre>
```

Comment: Where is the commenting that explains how this works?

Comment: Please can you explain the line after 'while'? As a beginner i am having slight difficulty in understanding it. Thx

Comment: no explanation !!!

Answer (score 4):

use the same program within `<center> </center>` tag ! like:

```
<center>
<?php

    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
                    echo "*";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }

?>
</center>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML whitespace character to procude the whitespaces: &nbsp;

So something like this:

```
<?php
// pyramid height
$height = 5;

for($i=1;$i<=$height;$i++){

    for($t = 1;$t <= $height-$i;$t++)
    {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }

    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {
        // use &nbsp; here to procude space after each asterix
        echo "*&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
echo "<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$height = 5;

$space = $height;
for($i = 1; $i <= $height; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', --$space);
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
        if($j > 1) {
            echo ' ';
        }
        echo '*';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create_pyramid("*", 5);

function create_pyramid($string, $level) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $level = $level * 2;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $level; $i ++) {
        if (!($i % 2) && $i != 1)
            continue;   
        print str_pad(str_repeat($string, $i),($level - 1) * strlen($string), " " , STR_PAD_BOTH);
        print PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

From [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12800236/1226894) posted above by [Baba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226894/baba)

Comment: It works with `'* '` as `$string` but not in the way OP wants. See [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0i9PMJ1t).

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 5;
$i = 0;

for($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++){

    echo "<pre>";   
    echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", $n-$i);
    echo str_repeat("#&nbsp;", $i);
}
```