# Creating Pyramid in PHP

Tags: php

I searched some code in php that creates the following output:

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

I noticed that there are lots of different approach they used to achieve this output. The other codes are long and the other is short. .

But there is one code that caught my attention. The code he used is too short and it's interesting for me, but I do not know how he do it because he did not left any explanation about it. The code is:

```
<pre><?php
$n = $i = 5;
while ($i--)
    echo str_repeat(' ', $i).str_repeat('* ', $n - $i)."\n";
?></pre>
```

I do not know how the code works. I think the `$n =$i = 5` is for the loop? Am I right? Is there anyone here can explain to me how the code works with simulation.

I found this code at [Pyramid of asterisks in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250725/pyramid-of-asterisks-in-php)

Any answers are welcome and much appreciated. Thank you guys!

Comment: Isn't the code pretty self-explaining ? I don't really see what should be unclear here.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, `$n = $i = 5;` is not a for loop. Sorry if I sound rude, but you should start with a basic PHP tutorial.

Comment: Which line don't you understand? #1 output `<pre>` and switch to PHP; #2 set two variables to a value of 5; #3 start a loop that will continue until one of those variables is a falsey value (0); #4 echo a line of the pyramid from top to bottom; #5 exit PHP and output a closing `</pre>`

Comment: You can understand easily how the code works if you play the role of the PHP interpreter; use pencil and paper to "run" the code line by line. On each line of code, evaluate the values of the expressions encountered and update the new values of the variables on a piece of paper. Use another piece of paper to keep the output of the program. This exercise will help you understand how computer programs work, no matter what language they are coded in.

Comment: @Yao ming: Explanation may help

Comment: @axiac: that's a good approach. Using a spreadsheet can do the same thing, with each cell to record space/star characters, and the variable values at each step.

Comment: Or use the excellent idea of @halfer. It is a real helper to understand how the recursive function calls work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:
**[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/lNpBU)**

```
<?php
$n = $i = 5;
while ($i--)
    echo str_repeat(' ', $i).str_repeat('* ', $n - $i)."\n";
```

**Loop 1:**
`$i = 5` (true) and decrement `$i` by 1, now `$i = 4`
`str_repeat(' ', $i)`, means print empty space 4 times
then `print '* '` `$n - $i` (5 - 4 = 1) time
**Present output:**

```
*
```

**Loop 2:**
`$i = 4` (true) and decrement `$i` by 1, now `$i = 3`
`str_repeat(' ', $i)`, means print empty space 3 times
then `print '* '` `$n - $i` (5 - 3 = 2) times
**Present output:**

```
 *
* *
```

**Loop 3:**
`$i = 3` (true) and decrement `$i` by 1, now `$i = 2`
`str_repeat(' ', $i)`, means print empty space 2 times
then `print '* '` `$n - $i` (5 - 2 = 3) times
**Present output:**

```
  *
 * *
* * *
```

**Loop 4:**
`$i = 2` (true) and decrement `$i` by 1, now `$i = 1`
`str_repeat(' ', $i)`, means print empty space 1 times
then `print '* '` `$n - $i` (5 - 1 = 4) times
**Present output:**

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

**Loop 5:**
`$i = 1` (true) and decrement `$i` by 0, now `$i = 0`
`str_repeat(' ', $i)`, means print empty space 0 times
then `print '* '` `$n - $i` (5 - 0 = 5) times
**Present output:**

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

**Loop 6:**
`$i = 0` (false) and loop breaks

Comment: Each of your outputs 1-4 should have more spaces to the left, but otherwise, good effort!

Comment: Thank you very much for the illustration I appreciated it so much. .